# Using puppeteer-extra with stealth mode in docker

Tags: docker, puppeteer

Trying to use puppeteer-extra and puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth in docker. When I use the recommended  puppeteer Dockerfile I get the errors

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/fonts.conf", line 100: unknown element "blank"
[18:18:0805/044421.419828:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1417)] Unable to open X display.
[0805/044421.443235:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!

I'm new to using docker, so I know my knowledge is not very good. Please let me know how to fix this. I keep trying different things but nothing works. I don't see anything about puppeteer-extra with docker, so im really at my wits end.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app

# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
    && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
    && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y google-chrome-unstable fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-wqy-zenhei fonts-thai-tlwg fonts-kacst fonts-freefont-ttf \
    && apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget x11vnc x11-xkb-utils xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-scalable xfonts-cyrillic x11-apps xvfb \

      --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* 


# If running Docker >= 1.13.0 use docker run's --init arg to reap zombie processes, otherwise
# uncomment the following lines to have `dumb-init` as PID 1
# ADD https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init/releases/download/v1.2.0/dumb-init_1.2.0_amd64 /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/dumb-init
# ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--"]

# Uncomment to skip the chromium download when installing puppeteer. If you do,
# you'll need to launch puppeteer with:
#     browser.launch({executablePath: 'google-chrome-unstable'})
# ENV PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD true

# Install puppeteer so it's available in the container.
RUN npm i puppeteer \
    # Add user so we don't need --no-sandbox.
    # same layer as npm install to keep re-chowned files from using up several hundred MBs more space
    && groupadd -r pptruser && useradd -r -g pptruser -G audio,video pptruser \
    && mkdir -p /home/pptruser/Downloads \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /home/pptruser \
    && chown -R pptruser:pptruser /app

# Run everything after as non-privileged user.
USER pptruser


CMD ["google-chrome-unstable"]
CMD xvfb-run --server-args="-screen 0 1024x768x24" npm start

CMD node setup.js
```

setup.js

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-extra');
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
puppeteer.use(StealthPlugin())
function delay(time) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, time)
  });
}
(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false, args: ['--no-sandbox']});
  const page = await browser.newPage();

await page.goto('https://www.google.com')

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1440, height: 821 })

await delay(20000)
})()
```

Comment: Please add samples of minimal code, Dockerfile and errors to your question.

Comment: Added the files

Comment: You're launching puppeteer with `headless: false`, but in Docker container there is no screen for it to show GUI, so it fails. Google `puppeteer xvfb`.

Comment: @Vaviloff the Dockerfile shows that puppeteer is being launched with xvfb-run

Comment: @BradFrost I believe it's not: `CMD node setup.js` (but the line above, `npm start` indeed is started with xvfb-run)

Comment: @Jaynic23 Please reply